# SELECT from table join

Tags: php, mysql

I have 3 tables:

```
users
  user_id
  first_name
forum_post
 post_id
 post_title
user_post_join
  id
  user_id
  post_id
```

The join table takes the user_id from users and post_id from forum_posts.

What I am trying to display is a list of posts from the forum_post table and the user who posted it. I am struggling to know where the join should be, here is my attempt so far...

```
function build_forum_posts(){

        global $dbc;

        $q = "SELECT users.user_id, forum_post.post_id, user_post_join.id 
            FROM users 
            INNER JOIN user_post_join ON users.user_id = forum_posts.post_id
             ";  

        $r = mysqli_query ($dbc, $q); // Run the query.

        // FETCH AND PRINT ALL THE RECORDS
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($r)) {

        echo '
        <div class="post">
            <div class="col-group-2">
                <h3>'.$row["post_id"]. '</h3>
                <p>By: '.$row["user_id"]. '</p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-group-2">
                <div class="post_count">
                    <h3  class="answer">0</h3>
                    <p class="answer">Answers</p>
                </div>
            </div>  
        </div>
        ';

        }
```

Comment: if its a question of sql syntax, why not try it in the mysql console or php myadmin to see if its right?

Comment: by the way, I think your issue is that you typed the tablename wrong after join

Comment: @developerwjk Ah yeah I saw the typo but still getting an error: `Warning: mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in C:\Program Files\Ampps\www\functions\functions.inc.php on line 787`

Comment: that error means the query failed so when you go to extract the result, there isn't one.

Comment: so I am trying to build the query in phpyadmin and really struggling, im really unsure on how to get the posts title and also the person who posted it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't join all three tables. Try something like this:

```
SELECT u.user_id, u.first_name, f.post_id, f.post_title, j.id 
 FROM users AS u
 INNER JOIN user_post_join AS j ON u.user_id = j.user_id
 INNER JOIN forum_posts AS f ON f.post_id = j.post_id
```

Comment: Hey, that is literally pretty much spot on, although it posts the title and th user but underneath its spits out a list of all my users

Comment: Depending on exactly what you wanna do, you might want to do the joins as `INNER` instead of `LEFT`. The former will return only matching results where as the latter will return all results regardless of if there was a match or not

Comment: Which is really fantastic but It just spits out the entire list- is there a way to refine it down to just the user who posted it?

Comment: Yeah so if you need just the posts and their users, you wanna do an `INNER JOIN`

Comment: @khuderm Thank you, after reading your comment and combining it with hellcodes answer it works perfectly.